# Trying to sen the progressValue of seekBar to server using OSC/UDP

Tags: java, android, osc

So, I am trying to send the progressValue of a seekBar to a server using OSC. However, I am not receiving any information on the server end.

The connection works, as I have radio buttons that all register, and a player registration that also works. Can anyone check this code snippet and offer some advice?

```
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbar, int progressValue,   boolean fromUser) {
      int step = 10;
        //  text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        if(seekbar == Size) {
            progressValue = ((int) Math.round(progressValue / step)) * step;

            sz = progressValue;
            Size.setProgress(progressValue);
            text.setText(String.valueOf(progressValue));

            try{
            //This is where the value is being sent to the server    
            sender.send(new OSCMessage("/update_size", sz));
            }catch(Exception E){
                text.setText("Catch 3: "
                        + E.getClass().getName() + ", "
                        + E.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Comment: What datatype is sz? Is it the same as the registered callback at the server? It might be discarded silently at the server if it didn't match the expected one.

Answer (score 0):

There is an array method I had to use to pass floats or ints in the message. I got around this by passing it as a text value, then parsing it on the server.